# play encrypted movies in vlc by decrypting them by ffmpeg "on the fly"

Tags: macos, encryption, ffmpeg, vlc, on-the-fly

I would like to play encrypted movies in vlc by decrypting them by ffmpeg like below on macOS.
The size of my movie is, say, 200-1000MB. (hundreds of files)

My problem is that it is too slow to decrypt; it takes 5mins for 300MB movie before it starts to play.
My guess is that ffmpeg first decrypts the whole content of 300MB and then VLC plays it.
My question: Is it possible to play the movie "on the fly" while decrypting it?
(play the decrypted chunk once it is decrypted, Not wait until the whole movie is decrypted before it plays, so that it starts to play in, say, 10 secs delay.)

```
ffmpeg -decryption_key 0 -i "movie.locked.mp4" -f matroska | /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC - --fullscreen --quiet --play-and-exit
```

Thank you very much!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't think the pipe to vlc is the problem. I use a small
utility to decrypt videos and also send it with the pipe 
method to vlc and the video starts after a few seconds.

You can download it (source included) from:

http://onlib.de/pub/pfv/pfv.zip

or execute the batch code at the end of this posting to generate
the executable pfv.exe.

There is also a demo file:

http://onlib.de/pub/pfv/demo.pfv  (33 MByte)

with a few small encrypted videos embedded. 

--------------------------------------------------------------

Privacy For Videos (aes256 encryption for videos)

This utility can be use to display encrypted videos in
combination with the VLC media player:

usage: pfv.exe number : password1 : password2 : inputfile >outputfile

password is a 43 character string with the characters A-Z a-z 0-9 / +
Any other character is ignored. If less characters are provided, the
string is padded with +. Therefore you should not use a password which
ends with a +, because, for example, the two passwords "abc" and "abc++++"
are both extended to "abc++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
and therefore "abc++++" is not more secure than "abc". The binary
256 bit key for aes is generated by base64 decoding the given 43
character password.

To encrypt a video file "video1.mp4" with the password "hello world"
(note: the space in the password is ignored, so "helloworld" or
"hello_world" would be the same), use:

pfv.exe :: hello world : video1.mp4 >video1.pfv

The file size of the output file is increased to a multiple
of 1 MByte.

Note: if you repeat this command, you will get a different
binary, but it still is a valid encrypted version of the video.


To decrypt this encrypted video use:

pfv.exe : hello world :: video1.pfv >video2.mp4

video1.mp4 and video2.mp4 are then identical files.


To directly play an encrypted video use:

pfv.exe : hello world :: video1.pfv | C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -


To re-encrypt a video with a different password without first
decrypting it (no decrypted version of the video is temporarily
stored on the disk), use:

pfv.exe : old password : new password : inputfile > outputfile


If you have more encrypted videos, for example:

video1.pfv (encrypted with password "pass1")
video2.pfv (encrypted with password "pass1")
video3.pfv (encrypted with password "pass2")
video4.pfv (encrypted with password "pass1")

you can copy them all into one big file (but there
is a 4 GByte limit for FAT filesystems):

copy /b video1.pfv + video2.pfv + video3.pfv + video4.pfv all.pfv

To play vidoe1 use:
pfv.exe : pass1 :: all.pfv | C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

To play vidoe2 use:
pfv.exe 2 : pass1 :: all.pfv | C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

To play vidoe3 use:
pfv.exe : pass2 :: all.pfv | C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

To play vidoe4 use:
pfv.exe 3 : pass1 :: all.pfv | C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

The number specifies which of the videos encrypted with 
the given password should be decrypted. If the number
is 0 or omitted, 1 is used (video4 is the 3. video 
encrypted with pass1 in the input file).

If you use ">outfile" instead of "|vlc -" you can 
extract the video from the multi-video file (encrypted
or unencrypted depending on a given second password).

The program is pretty slow, but a standard PC should be
be able to decode at least Full HD videos.



If you put this batch on your desktop,

@echo off
set /p p=Password: 
set p=&cls&pfv :%p%::%1|C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

you can use the mouse to drop a encrypted video on it.
It then asks for the password and plays the video.


If you use multi video files, use this batch:

@echo off
set /p p=Number:Password: 
set p=&cls&pfv %p%::%1|D:\Programme\vlc\vlc.exe -

In this case you must enter the number and password
separated by a ":", for example: 3:mypassword

--------------------------------------------------------------------

The demo file demo.pfv contains 3 videos and a zip file:

video 1:  a cat video
          password "only cats no dogs"
video 2:  a qr code video 
          password "hack me if you can"
video 3:  a picture slide show video 
          password again "only cats no dogs"
zip file: a zip file with some original pictures of the slide show
          password  "who cares"

to play video 1 use:
pfv :only cats no dogs::demo.pfv| C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

to play video 2 use:
pfv :hack me if you can::demo.pfv| C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

to play video 3 use:
pfv 2:only cats no dogs::demo.pfv| C:\path_to_vlc\vlc.exe -

to extract the zip file use:
pfv :who cares::demo.pfv > cats.zip

If you decode the qr code video, you will get a zip file
with some pictures. The password for the pictures is:
"The quick brown fox jump"

--------------------------------------------------------------------

Here the binary of pfv.exe (just execute the batch below to
generate the binary):


@echo off
certutil -f -decode %~f0 pfv.exe>nul
goto :eof

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply with detailed explanations. I have tried to download the pfv.zip on Windows10, which says it contains malicious software, and rejects it. Win10 finds "Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.H!ml" in the zip. Does it contain a virus or something alike? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There surely is no virus and I also don't
get a warning when downloading the zip file.

The content of the zip file is:

```
    3.584 pfv.exe             binary of the program 
   45.525 pfv.mac             source code
    9.486 readme.txt          text posted above
  167.704 windela.c           source code of the assembler
  205.582 windela.txt         documentation of the 486 assemnler (German)
  160.597 windela_e.txt       documentation of the 486 assemnler (English)
  121.856 windela32.exe       binary of the assembler
```

I copied the source code now also as text file on the server:
http://onlib.de/pub/pfv/pfv.mac.txt

You can generate the binary pfv.exe also by the above
posted batch program.

The assembler (windela.*) is only needed if you want
to make changes to the source code and assemble it.

Comment: Download pfv.zip is not possible because windows defender detects it as malicious. Make pfv.exe from certutil command is possible but pfv.exe is deleted immediately by windows defender.
Did you make this pfv.exe with assenmber? May I ask you why? Also is it possible to port it to macOS as in the original question? (Assemble code must be quite machine architecture dependent, and your code probably does not run on macOS.)
pfv.mac.txt seems to be a code for macOS. How can I make assemble the code?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can't answer as a comment, because only 600 
characters are allowed so I will add a new
answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Download pfv.zip is not possible because windows
> defender detects it as malicious. Make pfv.exe
> from certutil command is possible but pfv.exe is
> deleted immediately by windows defender.

Very strange. Here the Windows defender doesn't
complain and because every single byte in the
exe file is "hand made" by the assembler source
code (even the exe header) there also isn't anything
to complain.

> Did you make this pfv.exe with assenmber? May I
> ask you why?

A few years ago I wrote a small utility to encrypt
single files:

http://onlib.de/pub/assembler/aes32.zip

I used assembler because I wanted a small file
size and because it is the best language to
understand the details of the AES encryption.

Now I got aware, that VLC video player can read
a video from stdin so I did a small modification
to this program so now it is a bit faster and also
can store multiple videos in one file.

> Also is it possible to port it to macOS as in
> the original question? (Assemble code must be
> quite machine architecture dependent, and your
> code probably does not run on macOS.)

There should be many free C implementation of the
AES algorithm. If you don't need the feature to
store more videos in one file, then all you have
to change is, to not write to an output file but
to stdout.

> pfv.mac.txt seems to be a code for macOS.

No, the ".mac" is just a reminiscence on the
first assembler I used, the one of the PDP11.

> How can I make assemble the code? Thank you very much!

It doesn't work on an Apple, it is Intel 386 code.